# Is it possible to append html code in parts via JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append `li` elements coming from a php file with JQuery. Problem is that the html code needs to be seperately appended to different html IDs according to the key value. Unfortunately as I understood `append()` can only append correct html with all elements closed. Otherwise it will automatically close the tags. The following code will NOT work as `dval` contains code like `<div><li class="some">Some value</li>` and `append()` will make `<div><li class="some">Some value</li></div>` out of it. So I was wondering whether there is another way, maybe a function other than `append()` to be able to append html parts?

EDIT:

This is my Jquery:

```
$.getJSON("../ajax.php", function(data)
{
    $.each(obj, function(key,val)
    {
        $.each(obj[key], function(key, dval)
        {                       
            if(key == "text")
            {                   
                $("#" + key).append(dval);
            }           
        })          
    });
});
```

This is my PHP:

```
$json_arr = $json_arr."[";
if($counter % 2 == 0)
{
    $arr[0] = preg_replace('#<td class="some">(.*?)</td>#', '<li id="1234"><span class="some">$1</span>', $ja[0]);
}
else $ja[0] = preg_replace('#<td class="some">(.*?)</td>#', '<span class="some2">$1</span><div class="somediv"></div></li>', $ja[0]);

$json->id = $closest_key; // Closest key is the ID of an existing li element which is the closest to the current word
$json->text = $ja[0];
$json_arr = $json_arr.'{"id":"'.$json->id.'", "text":"'.addslashes($json->text).'"},';
$json_arr = substr($json_arr,0,-1);
$json_arr = $json_arr."]";
echo(json_encode($json_arr));
```

Now if counter is even `<li id="1234"><span class="some">$1</span>` should be appended to `$closest_key`, if it is odd then `<span class="some2">$1</span><div class="somediv"></div></li>` should be appended.

Comment: What's the problem with closing the div? If div is closed it doesn't mean you can't append anything further.

Comment: What if you firstly append a whole div, and then append your list elements into that new div?

Comment: Have you tried `.html()`? This doesn't seem like a very good approach.

Comment: No there is'nt, and no you should'nt. Try to stick with the generally accepted practice of only appending actual elements.

Comment: `<li>` should be placed inside list tag only. `<div><li></li` is not valid anyway

Comment: @Blender: `.html()` will replace existing content, I want to append it
@Renty: the problem is that the next dval will contain something like `<span id="some"></span></div>`

Comment: @phpheini it would be helpful if you show a structure of `obj` and maybe built a http://jsfiddle.net as it is not completely clear what should be shown in result and what is the initial data

Comment: you could try .html() or javascripts innerHTML, but its not recommended since most modern browser automatically evaluate the DOM and try to fix it for themselves, so bad things could be happening. as @Hast said, try to append the div and then append the ul li into the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not realy jquery that is adding the closing tag, its your browser. In order to render a webpage it needs to have a valid HTML DOM and it will try to fix errors for you.

What you are doing will be very slow with a large obj, because after every append the entire page will be recreated (meaning every width/height/position must be recalculated). (google javascript reflow / repaint)

The best thing to do is to create the full HTML strings first and then append it.

```
var html = {};
$.each(obj, function(key,val)
{
    $.each(obj[key], function(key, dval)
    {                       
        if(key == "text")
        {            
            if (html[key]==undefined)
              html[key] = "";

            html[key] += dval.toString();
        }           
    })          
}); 

$.each(html, function(key,val)
{
    $("#" + key).append(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build up a string of HTML and then append all at once.

Heres an example.

```
var html = '<div><ul>';

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    html += '<li>Test</li>';
}
html += '</ul></div>';
jQuery('#test').html(html);
```

Comment: I need to append the html code to a specific html element with the ID inside my `key` variable.

Comment: Could you give me an example of your data please?

Answer (score 0):

You are always appending to `$('#text')`, so why not just build the string, and append it afterwards?

```
var html = '';

$.each(obj, function(key,val) {
    $.each(obj[key], function(key, dval) {
        if(key == "text") { //the element being appended to is always #text anyway ?
            html += dval;
        }           
    });
});

$('#text').append(html);
```